# "PasswordHash" does not have accessor method "getPasswordHash" in class "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface"

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am calling this endpoint /rest/V1/customers/me to change user password thorugh PUT request with request body:

```
   {
   "customer": {
       "firstname": "abc",
       "lastname": "abc",
       "email":"rrr@gmail.com",
       "website_id": 0,
       "addresses": [
           {
               "region": {
                   "region_code": "21",
                   "region": "Pakistan",
                   "region_id": 92
               },
               "region_id": 92,
               "country_id": "PK",
               "street": [
                   "assa"
               ],
               "city": "lahore",
               "firstname": "def",
               "lastname": "def",
               "telephone": "98798798798",
               "postcode": "987987",

               "default_shipping": true,
               "default_billing": true

           }
       ],
       "passwordHash"  : "Admin123123"

   }
   }
```

I am getting this error:

**"message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5cacb11c9a67c**

When i've checked the magento log file it shows me this exception:

**Message: Property "PasswordHash" does not have accessor method "getPasswordHash" in class "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface"**

I have seen this ref but it didn't works for me. [Magento 2: Property does not have accessor method in class "Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionInterface](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247328/magento-2-property-does-not-have-accessor-method-in-class-magento-checkout-api)

Please help!

Comment: why would you want to do this?!?!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the dedicated endpoint to change the password

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me/password" method="PUT">
```

Example Body:

`{
  "currentPassword": "string",
  "newPassword": "string"
}`

Comment: Bro thanks for your reply ... we need to use the same endpoint

Comment: no.... don't do this! use the ones you are supposed to use! also as stated in the word "hash" is that it's something generated. so you can' pass a plain text into this

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue trying to create customer accounts (for importing and testing purposes).  I have generated a correctly hashed password but recieve the same error:

*Report ID: webapi-5d1daf169fdd6; Message: Property "PasswordHash" does not have accessor method "getPasswordHash" in class "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface". {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5d1daf169fdd6; Message: Property \"PasswordHash\" does not have accessor method \"getPasswordHash\" in class \"Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface\". at /vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:206, LogicException(code: 0): Property \"PasswordHash\" does not have accessor method \"getPasswordHash\" in class \"Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface\". at /vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"}*

This is the payload being sent to the **rest/V1/customers/me** endpoint:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "group_id": 1,
        "email": "importtest@testemail.co.uk",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "store_id": 1,
        "website_id": 1,
        "addresses": [
            {
                "region": {
                    "region_code": "Edinburgh",
                    "region": "Edinburgh"
                },
                "country_id": "GB",
                "street": [
                    "1 Haggis Road"
                ],
                "telephone": "07777454545",
                "postcode": "EH10 1AA",
                "city": "Edinburgh",
                "firstname": "John",
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "default_billing": true,
                "default_shipping": true
            }
        ],
        "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
        "passwordHash": "9dce90d384b9882b7a67710e2c66ba3c42c8b230aa227b8074cd9413604c22df:wYp9suAxdO1ZdPpcRwgKcKyjr6xdWaI1:1"
    }
}
```

The password that has been hashed is **M9b@WZ7C** using the Salt **wYp9suAxdO1ZdPpcRwgKcKyjr6xdWaI1**.

Any ideas?